# Centering GridView in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to center my GridView in a RelativeLayout. I set the GridView's height to wrap_content and gravity of the RelativeLayout is center, but the GridView is still aligned at the top. Here is what I have:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sixerstrivia.MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/dashboardGrid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="20dp" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I center this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `android:gravity` on your `RelativeLayout`, you should use [android:layout_centerVertical](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_centerVertical):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sixerstrivia.MainActivity" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/dashboardGrid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="20dp" >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add these to your GridView:  `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Remove center gravity from the RelativeLayout. add this to your GridView:

```
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

Comment: This did not help...same result

Comment: RelativeLayout does not support `layout_gravity` - that is unique to `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout`, and `GridLayout`

Comment: Yeah it would be listed under [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) if it was supported